# Function return type based on the elements of array passed as an argument

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-generics, object-literal

I'm trying to find a way to create function which return type depends on the elements of array passed as an argument

```js
const arr1 = ['a', 'b'] as const
const arr2 = ['a', 'c'] as const

func(arr1)     // return type {a: any, b: any}
func(arr1).a   // ok
func(arr1).b   // ok
func(arr1).c   // TYPE ERROR

func(arr2)     // return type {a: any, c: any}
func(arr2).a   // ok
func(arr2).b   // TYPE ERROR
func(arr2).c   // ok
```

So something like that but actually working

```
function func<T>(array: T): {[K in typeof array[number]]: any}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close!

```
function func<A extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(array: A): { [K in A[number]]: any } { ... }
```

`A[number]` will give us a union of all the strings inside it, and then  we can map over that.

You can think of the generic here as a "retaining" the type of `array` over to the return type so we can use it.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVLTAB4BBeEADwxFWAGd4AlEKYPCATxJhig6LoYYWVAHMAfOIAUsXhwBc8EgEpFAb3gBtANLwRSzamQBbAEYgYAXUuKoqDvAC+AbgCwAKA9g8g+LICM8AC8WgDkUKEANPChpqGWfgzeqIJePhh+PABMwWER0aFg8Ynwyame7ijoMjz+yvANDQD0TfBwGMgw+BgcAA4IalC29tGmwxyOHlVgNTB1AHRQjS3wOADWU4SzC6bLreub1QHK82B78AAqAJoACgCi8HeMjADyjB6HM7JZ9Y3wK+1Ot0+gMhn4RqVxpNKltvicls19hsYUdsiddojLrcHk9Xu8UV80adzusgA)